# Method not visible upon action support

Tags: apex, visualforce

1. I have a requirement where I have to disable the checkbox based on change of picklist values.
2. I have made use of action support
3. Iam wrapping the picklist using action region and on action I’m calling the apex method and re rendering the Checkbox to true/false. But when I change the picklist value, the page says method is not visible, though I have made method as public.

Not sure what is going wrong, can someone have experienced the same, if so, please assist the workaround.

Comment: In some cases, like an iframe (IIRC), you need to make the method global instead).

Comment: I agree with @sfdcfox. If still it is not working add your code so that it will be easy for us to guide you.